# Convert CharBuffer to ByteBuffer

Tags: java, character-encoding, buffer

It is easy to convert a `ByteBuffer` to `CharBuffer` using `ByteBuffer.asCharBuffer()`.

How do I go in the other direction?
Is there a simpler way than [`ByteBuffer Charset.encode(CharBuffer cb)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#encode-java.nio.CharBuffer-)?

`CharBuffer` stores its data in an internal `char[]` and not `byte[]` therefore there is no underlying `byte[]` so there should be no simpler way.

Comment: Just to set it straight, it doesn’t create a `CharBuffer`, it creates a `CharBuffer` view of the remaining part of the `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: You may write back into the `ByteBuffer` through the `CharBuffer` view. Wonder if this gives you what you want? Maybe you should try to explain at a higher level what you are trying to obtain and why you are asking the question.

Comment: It’s not my home field, so I could be all wrong: `ByteBuffer.wrap(yourCharBuffer.toString().getBytes())`? You may optionally pass a `CharSet` or a char set name to `getBytes()` to control the character encoding.

Comment: `Charset.encode(CharBuffer cb)` would seem pretty direct to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a suggestion.

```
    CharBuffer yourCharBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap("Roland");

    ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.allocate(yourCharBuffer.length() * Character.BYTES);
    CharBuffer converter = result.asCharBuffer();
    converter.append(yourCharBuffer);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.array()));
```

The above snippet prints:

> [0, 82, 0, 111, 0, 108, 0, 97, 0, 110, 0, 100]

I am getting the byte array out that is simultaniously backing the `converter` `CharArray` and the `result` `ByteArray`. It’s as close as I can get to your requirements. I may be missing something.

Edit: following the suggestion by @Marcono1234 in the comment I am using `ByteBuffer.allocate(yourCharBuffer.length() * Character.BYTES)` to allocate a correctly sized buffer.

If the code that filled your original `CharBuffer` could instead fill you byte buffer backed `CharBuffer`, it could be a bit simpler.

And you own suggestion, `Charset.encode(CharBuffer)`, is simpler still.

Comment: You can use `ByteBuffer.allocate(yourCharBuffer.length() * Character.BYTES)` to allocate a correctly sized buffer.

Comment: No problem. And you might get better performance by using `CharBuffer.put(CharBuffer)` instead of `CharBuffer.append(CharSequence)` (however `put` will also increase the position of the given buffer, but in your example this does not matter). Currently in OpenJDK `append` first [creates a string](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/f0b93fbd8cf8/src/share/classes/java/nio/X-Buffer.java.template#l1351), whereas `put` [uses `System.arraycopy`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/f0b93fbd8cf8/src/share/classes/java/nio/Heap-X-Buffer.java.template#l207).

Comment: Edit: My previous comment was partially wrong. The `CharBuffer` is actually a `ByteBufferAsCharBufferB`, so it will not use `System.arraycopy`. But it might still perform better because it directly [gets each of the chars and puts them](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/f0b93fbd8cf8/src/share/classes/java/nio/X-Buffer.java.template#l770).